# Windows api GetClientRect issue

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following function and code to try to get the size of a client window in vb.net, I don't think I have any issues with my Rect structure.

Why do I get this error:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Can you get this to work for me please?

```
Private Declare Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal _
    hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpRect As Rect) As Boolean

Dim lobbywindow As Long = windowhwnd
Dim lobbyrect As New Rect

GetClientRect(lobbywindow, lobbyrect)
```

Comment: Lobbywindow should be an IntPtr. See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getclientrect for the Rect, as you need to declare a structure for it. Is there any reason not to use Control.ClientRectangle?

Comment: Did you look at the pinvoke link and follow the link to the RECT structure?

Comment: Works perfectly now, had to nose about on that site a bit more but got it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getclientrect](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getclientrect) for the Rect, as you need to declare a structure for it.